# how to calculate diff year with non-standard datetime format in mysql

Tags: mysql

My database(MySQL 5.7) store the user birthday format like this `1990年1月1日`, now I want to calculate the user age from this format datetime. My sql look like this but return null for all data:

```
select period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y'), date_format(birthday, '%Y年')) as months 
from spark_user;
```

the table DDL look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `spark_user` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `birthday` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I also tried like this:

```
select period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y'), date_format(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%Y'), '%Y')) as months 
from spark_user;
```

this works:

```
    select period_diff( date_format(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%Y年%m月%d日'), '%Y'),date_format(now(), '%Y')) as months,
birthday as birthday 
from spark_user;
```

but the result is strange:

```
57  1990年1月1日
57  1990年1月1日
57  1990年1月1日
57  1990年10月10日
47  1980年1月1日
-20 2001年1月1日
63  1996年10月10日
```

Comment: Convert to standard DATE then calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YEAR(CURDATE()) - LEFT(birthday, 4)
```

Note:  It will be off by up to 1 year, depending on the current date and when in the year they were born.

Answer (score 1):

> store the user **birthday format** like this ...

One of the many unwritten Rules about Relational databases -

> Dates have *no format* ...

... or, at least, none that *you or I* need worry about.

If you *think* that your Dates have a "format", then you're looking almost certainly at **Character** data, not proper **Dates** and, as you've discovered, trying to work with character data that just happens to contain Date values is *difficult*.

Always use the Right Data Type for the Right Job.

Sure, STR_TO_DATE converts a character value into a **Date** value, but does so according to the database's own rules.
When, exactly, is 01/04/07?  January?  April?  2001 or 2007?
(You'll find the one that works for you and all will be well - until you have to port your database to some other DBMS, with different rules and all Hell breaks loose).
Also, using a function into this way prevents the database from using any index you have on that field - Table Scanning, here we come.

Answer (score 0):

I use this sql command, works:

```
select YEAR(now()) - YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%Y年%m月%d日'))
```